# Problem in defining Route{ throw new InvalidArgumentException("Route [{$name}] not defined.");}

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-routing, laravel-authorization

I'm using auth() in Laravel 5.7 .I have to set values of role by default on different page which I copied as studentRegister.blade.php from register.blade.php

in web.php

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::get('student/register','Auth\RegisterController@registerStudent');

Route::get('teacher/register','Auth\RegisterController@registerTeacher');
```

in (Auth/RegisterController.php)

```
    public function registerStudent()
{ $role_id = 1;
return view('auth.registerStudent',compact('role_id'));
}


 public function registerTeacher()
 { $role_id = 2;
 return view('auth.register',compact('role_id'));
 }
```

setted value of hidden input with "role" name (Auth/Register.Blade.php);

```
<input id="role" type="hidden" name="role" value="{{$role}}">
```

In student.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')


<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Register') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('registerStudent') }}">
                        @csrf
                        {{ Session::get('success') }}


                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Name') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('name'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="password" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>



                        <input id="role_id" type="hidden" name="role_id" value="1">


                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Register') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

It opens page register.blade.php when I use auth.register in registerController but it gives error

```
 throw new InvalidArgumentException("Route [{$name}] not defined.");
```

when I use  auth.StudentRegister in registerController

Comment: You can't use `route('registerStudent')` unless you have a route named `registerStudent`, like `Route::get("...")->name("registerStudent");`

Comment: I have used the code as CodeBoy told but now I'm having exception in Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Comment: I know; already commented on what you need to do to fix that error on your other question. Both of the issues you posted are common; you should do some research on the errors before you post a question.

Answer (score 2):

This should hopefully fix it:

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::get('student/register','Auth\RegisterController@registerStudent')->name('auth.registerStudent');

Route::get('teacher/register','Auth\RegisterController@registerTeacher')->name('auth.registerTeacher');
```

alternatively you could use a group, like so:

```
Route::name('auth.')->group(function () {
    Route::get('teacher/register','Auth\RegisterController@registerTeacher')->name('registerStudent');
    Route::get('teacher/register','Auth\RegisterController@registerTeacher')->name('registerTeacher')
});
```

and also change this:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('registerStudent') }}">
```

to

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('auth.registerStudent') }}">
```

I hope that helps :)

Comment: I'm having exception in

 Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException